# Printing text in two columns using ansi escape characters

Tags: c, ansi-escape

I am trying to print one string in the left half of the terminal and another one in the right half of the terminal. I have to achieve this using ANSI escape sequences, not ncurses. I also want to make sure, that no word is split at the end of the line. If the line doesn't have enough space to print the word, I want to print the word on the next line.

I have tried replacing move calls with printf(\n) and then using move to get to the required half of the screen. The move call seems to ignored entirely.

```c
#define clear() printf("\033[H\033[J")

void move(int y, int x)
{
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", y, x);
}

void print_left_right(int cols, char * left, char * right)
{
    clear();
    int cols_end = cols / 2;
    int line = 0;
    int current_pos = 0;
    char * l_split = strtok(left, " ");
    move(0, 0);
    while (l_split != NULL)
    {
        current_pos += (strlen(l_split) + 1); // plus one for space
        if (current_pos >= cols_end)
        {
            line += 1; // <----- doesn't seem to work
            move(line, 0); // <----- seems to work
            current_pos = 0;
        }
        printf("%s ", l_split);
        l_split = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    line = 0;
    current_pos = cols_end;
    char * r_split = strtok(right, " ");
    move(0, cols_end);
    while (r_split != NULL)
    {
        current_pos += (strlen(r_split) + 1);
        if (current_pos >= cols)
        {
            ++line;
            move(line, cols_end);
            current_pos = cols_end;
        }
        printf("%s ", r_split);
        r_split = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

I split given strings into words using strtok, and try to print it. If the word doesn't fit, I expected the line variable to increment and move to another line.
However the line variable does not increment and this code always rewrites the same line. Strangely, the move seems to correctly move to the correct half of the terminal.
I guess I'm doing something incredibly stupid...

Comment: Why do you need ANSI escape sequences ? Why not something like `printf("%*s%s\n", width, str1, str2);` with `width` the width of your (first) column. Add some additional logic to make sure `str1` and `str2` are no longer than `width`, and you have a working solution.

Comment: oh, I should have metioned it in the text, but checked the option while asking question, so I though it would be visible. anyways, this is a homework and I am required to use escape chars.

Comment: A standard (ECMA-48) terminal will interpret a zero-coordinate as **`1`**.  The program logic may not account for this.